# How can I display a plot in Repl.it using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, replit

I am trying to display a plot in Repl.it.

The following program works fine as it is able to generate proper output:

```
import turtle 
import math 

wn = turtle.Screen() 
turt = turtle.Turtle() 

turt.backward(180) 
turt.forward(360) 
turt.stamp() 
turt.backward(180) 
turt.left(90) 
turt.forward(100) 
turt.stamp()
turt.backward(200) 
turt.forward(100) 
turt.right(90) 
turt.backward(180) 

for i in range(-180, 181): 
  turt.goto(i, math.sin(math.radians(i)) * 100);
```

[image]

But, the following program

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 1.0
a = 0.4
λ = 1.4


def X(ϕ):
    return (A + a) * math.cos(ϕ) - λ * a * math.cos(((A + a) / a) * ϕ)


def Y(ϕ):
    return (A + a) * math.sin(ϕ) - λ * a * math.sin(((A + a) / a) * ϕ)


x_list = []
y_list = []

for i in range(0, 10001, 1):
    ϕ = i / 1000.0
    x_list.append(X(ϕ))
    y_list.append(Y(ϕ))

print(len(x_list))
print(len(y_list))

plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

just gives a blank screen and the following message:

```
10001
10001

XOpenDisplay(MAGIC)

Must DL Open Symbol
```

[image]

How can I display a plot in Repl.it using matplotlib?

**Edit.** Someone pointed out that my source code is missing `plt.show()`. This is strange. Because I didn't require this function call when I was working in Spyder.

Why doesn't Spyder require us to call `plt.show()`?

Comment: Not sure about the error, but you are missing `plt.show()` at the end. Add it and then run. It worked for me (although console shows the same error)

Comment: @MoosaSaadat, It worked. But, I didn't require it when I was working in Spyder.